# Unzipping using tar: --exclude too greedy: how to exclude only root-level file?

Tags: tar, zip

I’m on a Mac, El Capitan.

My zip file structure:

```
README.md
source/README.md
```

I can’t seem to `--exclude` the root-level `README.md` without also excluding the one in the `source` directory too.

I’ve been trying variations of things, like:

```
# Doesn’t exclude anything:
tar -xf master.zip --strip-components 1 --exclude=/README.md
tar -xf master.zip --strip-components 1 --exclude=/{install.sh,README.md}

# Excludes both files:
tar -xf master.zip --strip-components 1 --exclude=./README.md
tar -xf master.zip --strip-components 1 --exclude={install.sh,README.md}
tar -xf master.zip --strip-components 1 --exclude=./{install.sh,README.md}
```

#### Question:

How can I exclude **only** the root-level `README.md`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, tar may exclude files with `--anchored`

> patterns match file name start

But then you have to write the whole file path (which also changes with `cd`):

```
$ cd /where/source/lives
$ tar -cf master.zip --anchored --exclude={source/install.sh,README.md} -- *
```

If you need some flexibility, use find.
The list of files to be compressed may be created with this command,
the `! -name README.md` rejects the base `README.md` file :

```
$ path="/path/to/files"
$ find "$path/" ! -path  "$path"/README.md -print
```

Be careful with the slashes `/`, they do matter.
If that contains the correct list of files to compress, then just inject that to `tar` (add a `0` to `-print` and create the `tar` command):

```
find "$path/" ! -path  "$path"/README.md -print0 |
tar --no-recursion --null -T- --exclude=install.sh -v -cf master.zip
```

Note that `tar` is using the `--null` option to match the `-print0` of `find`.

As `find` is providing all the recursion needed, use tar's `--no-recursion` option.

Also, the file `install.sh` is still being excluded in `tar` (which might as well have been removed with `find`, but that is just personal preference).

In production, remove the `-v` option to get a less verbose tar command.

---

To decompress (instead of compress as above), use this:

```
tar -xf master.zip --anchored --exclude={source/install.sh,README.md}
```

Or, if you use the second option to create the compressed file, the files excluded will not be inside `master.zip` and all you would need to do is:

```
tar -xf master.zip
```

Comment: +1 for paying more attention to the man page than I did and finding `--anchored`, but `find somedir \! -name README.md` will reject *all* files named `README.md`, not just the top-level one.  You would need to use `-path` instead.

Comment: @larsks Solved `-name` issue. Anything else?

Comment: This is very instructional and useful @BinaryZebra, thank you! Unfortunately, I was not able to get --anchored to work on my version of tar on Mac OS X. I did try your other suggestions … I wasn't able to get your other options to work as it seemed to compress rather than decompress. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious. :(

Comment: @mhulse Yes, the commands are compressing.  You need de-compressing? changing `c` to `x` should be easy. Let me work it out.

Comment: @mhulse Well, to use the `--anchored` option you do need GNU tar. Which is [very easy to install](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities). Maybe you could [try using a `^` at the beginning of the pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511406/tar-exclude-single-files-directories-not-patterns#comment23613432_15909437) with your version of `bsd tar`. Your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Someone may show up with a better answer, but if tar's `--exclude` option isn't cutting it, you can use `find` to generate a list of files and then feed that `tar`.  For example:

```
find * -path README.md -prune -o -print | 
tar --no-recursion -cf /tmp/data.tar -T-
```

This prints a list of all files (and directories) that are not the top-level `README.md`, and then feeds them to `tar`, which reads its list of files from `stdin` (using `-T-`).  The `--no-recursion` flag is necessary because otherwise `tar` will automatically include all files in directories, which you don't want because these files will also be produced by `find` and you would end up with multiple files in the archive with the same name.

A more robust version might look like:

```
find * -path README.md -prune -o -print0 | 
tar --no-recursion -cf /tmp/data.tar --null -T-
```

Here, the `-print0` to `find` and the `--null` to `tar` mean that filenames will be separated by ASCII NUL characters rather than whitespace, which means the pipeline would handle filenames containing spaces.

Comment: Thanks so much for you help! I really appreciate it! I was not able to get it to work for my particular situation as it seemed to compress `master.zip` rather than decompress it. I feel terrible that I might have not made my question more clear (I've updated the title to include "unzip"). Then again, I could just be doing it wrong, or missing something obvious  (I apologize either way). With that said, I'm learning a ton, so not all is lost. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [`pax`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pax.1.html) utility has an exclusion feature that's a bit broader than BSD tar. Its `-s` option lets you transform names as they are stored or extracted, and if a name is transformed to an empty string, that file is excluded.

(BSD tar has a somewhat similar `-s` option, but going by the documentation, it doesn't seem to have the exclusion-on-empty feature.)

```
zcat foo.tar.gz | pax -r -pe -s'!^README\.md$!!' -s'!^\./README\.md$!!'
```

Note that I'm assuming a (possibly compressed) tar file. If you have a zip file, use [`unzip`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/unzip.1.html) instead.

```
unzip foo.zip -x 'README.md'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I finally have time to get back to testing things tonight, I'll let you know how it goes! +1